# spring boot, authentification flow with MariaDB and JWT OAuth2

Tags: spring, jdbc, oauth-2.0, jwt, mariadb

i want to create an authentifcation based on JWT.
The user credentials are in Mariadb database and i use jdbc driver for database access. I want to make an OAuth2 request with password grandType like this

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: authorization-server.com
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password
&username=exampleuser
&password=1234luggage
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
```

src: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/29/what-is-the-oauth2-password-grant

To have a response with access_token and refresh_token.

I've used similar configuration like this
https://github.com/nydiarra/springboot-jwt/tree/master/src/main/java/com/nouhoun/springboot/jwt/integration/config

I don't really understand how system works to get and compare user credentials in stored in database.
I've really need to have a specific database schema to works with OAuth2 server ? Like this https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs
I've an existing database, can i specify the logic to validate the user credentials data sent ?

Thx for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the way you fetch the user data from database by overriding the userdetailsservice.
This bean fetches the user from the database. 
Please refer to this article for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

Comment: Thx ! I've solved my problem by overriding UserDetailsService